# Get data of specific cell from selected row in DataGrid WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datagrid

I have a DataGrid which I fill with data from my sql database.
Now I want to get a specific cell (2nd cell) from the row I selected with a checkbox.

This is what I have now:
WPF XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="myGrid">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Checked="CheckBox_Checked"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="CustomerID" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding CustomerID}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ItemID" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding ItemID}"/>
<DataGrid>
```

C# code:

```
private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid row = (DataGrid)myGrid.SelectedItems[1];
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(row);
    }
```

I get a error when running:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
>
> {"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.\r\nParameter name: index"}

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to use another approach to get the cell I want?

Comment: Which cell data you want? As per posted XAML, it only contains one cell with checkBox in it.

Comment: I can't see any data in your DataGrid? How is it populated?

Comment: I left out some code, thought it wasn't necessary. @GáborBirkás

Comment: @thbl Are you using MVVM pattern? Why not bind your DataGrid context to an ObservableCollection containing your database rows? I can give you code for that if you want.

Comment: Yes please @GáborBirkás Hopefully I can then make it work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally found it! Very simple.

```
DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)myGrid.SelectedItem; 
String result = (drv["CustomerID"]).ToString(); 
MessageBox.Show(result);
```

Comment: not working. It display cast error.
        "Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType0`13"

Answer (score 7):

MVVM Pattern.

Your XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="myGrid" Grid.Row="1"  SelectionMode="Single" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}" IsReadOnly="True" Background="#FFB8C1CB">
<DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding yourColumnItem}" />

    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<YourType> YourCollection { get; private set; }
public DelegateCommand checkCommand { get; private set; }


public YourViewModel(){
    checkCommand = new checkCommand(param => checkExecuted(param));
}

private void CheckExecuted(Object param)
{
        YourType item = param as YourType;

        YourCollection = new ObservableCollection<YourType>();
        YourCollection = model.ReadInvoices();  //you'll need a model class
        DoStuff(item.yourColumnItem);  //get the cell you want
}
```

App.xaml.cs

```
private YourViewModel _ViewModel;

public App()
{
   _ViewModel = new YourViewModel();
}

protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
        base.OnStartup(e);

        _MainWindow = new MainWindow();
        _MainWindow.DataContext = _ViewModel;
        _MainWindow.Show();
        //delete the startupuri row from App.xaml

}
```

Your DelegateCommand class:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace yourSolution.ViewModel
{

public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<Object> _Execute; 
    private readonly Func<Object, Boolean> _CanExecute; 


    public DelegateCommand(Action<Object> execute) : this(null, execute) { }


    public DelegateCommand(Func<Object, Boolean> canExecute, Action<Object> execute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        }

        _Execute = execute;
        _CanExecute = canExecute;
    }


    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;


    public Boolean CanExecute(Object parameter)
    {
        return _CanExecute == null ? true : _CanExecute(parameter);
    }


    public void Execute(Object parameter)
    {
        _Execute(parameter);
    }


    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
            CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
}
```

DatabaseModel.cs:

```
public ObservableCollection<YourType> ReadInvoices()
{
        Connect();  //write connection
        YourCollection.Clear();  //this is a private data part
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(write your query);
        MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        YourCollection.Clear();
        YourType item = new YourType();

        while (dr.Read()){
          item.column = dr.GetInt32("columnName"); //or any other type
          YourCollection.Add(item);
        }

        dr.Close();
        Disconnect();

return YourCollection;
}
```

Bind your command in the xaml to the selected item. This way it will become the parameter for CheckCommand:

```
Command="{Binding CheckCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myGrid, Path=SelectedItem}"
```

I hope this covers everything. Of course you'll need EventHandlers to communicate with App.xaml.cs but I don't know what you want to do after processing your cell. I've only done this 3 times, I hope it works out.

Comment: Thank you for your trouble, but I can't seem to make it work. I thought it would be realy simple to get a cell out of a datagrid.

Comment: -1 for a totally unnecessarily and overly complicated answer. There is no need for 95% of your answer... the question author just wants to get a value from their `DataGrid`, not learn MVVM... they didn't even add an MVVM tag or mention it anywhere in their question. Our aim here is to help the question authors, not unnecessarily confuse them.

Comment: @Sheridan If you check my comment to the original question you will see that I specifically asked if the author wanted an answer with MVVM pattern. I wouldn't have posted a lengthy answer in any other case. Man, I just wanted to help with some code that by the way contains a fully reusable delegate command class. I wouldn't have needed to write down how to read in stuff from the db it was for clearing things up. And btw I've myself asked some questions around here, response to half of which was something like why do you need this? etc. Not actual help or code. Funny community.

Comment: You make a good point and looking back, I suppose it *was* silly down voting a user 'over answering' a question... it *is* better than 'under answering' questions, which many users do. However, I believe that my point stands... if you look at the question author's solution, you should see that too. It *is* too much of an answer for this question. Having said that, I see that you're relatively new and wanting to encourage users that *are* willing to take the time to provide full answers, I've had a complete change of heart. So apologies for before and +1 for a good answer and justification.

Comment: @Sheridan Thank you very much! It's nice to come across men who value things. Now I feel bad about what I've said about the community. I take that back - and will try to answer in a more proper way from now on.

Comment: I don't believe this code actually works.  The object passed in will always return null.....

Answer (score 3):

Use this it 100% working.

```
object item = dataGrid1.SelectedItem;
           string ID = (dataGrid1.SelectedCells[0].Column.GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock).Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get the value from the selected row of the property that is data bound to the second column of your `DataGrid`. However, the code that you showed us does *not* do that:

```
private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid row = (DataGrid)myGrid.SelectedItems[1]; // <--- 2nd item, not 2nd column!
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(row);
}
```

Your error was telling you...

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index

... because you were trying to access the second item from the `SelectedItems` collection when there was only one (or no) item selected. Therefore, your used index (`1`) was out of range.

However, once you fixed that error, you would have immediately found another telling you that there is no default cast set up between a `DataGrid` (the type of your `row` parameter) and whatever type you have in the `DataGrid`, again due to this line:

```
DataGrid row = (DataGrid)myGrid.SelectedItems[1];
```

This should be...

```
YourDataType row = myGrid.SelectedItems[0];
```

... because the `SelectedItems` property returns the items from the collection that are selected. Once you have the data item from the selected row, then all you need to do is access the desired property from it... I believe that you were after the `ItemID` property value:

```
int ItemId = row.ItemID;
```

Comment: I finally found it! Very simple. DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)myGrid.SelectedItem; String result = (drv["CustomerID"]).ToString();  MessageBox.Show(result);

Answer (score 0):

in wpf this one worked for me

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGridShowStudents">
</DataGrid>

private void dataGridShowStudents_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e){
        DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)dataGridShowStudents.SelectedItem;
        string result = drv[0].ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
YourDataGrid.SelectedIndex = X; 
DataRowView v = (DataRowView)YourDataGrid.SelectedItem;
TextBox1.Text = v[0].ToString();
TextBox2.Text = v[1].ToString();
TextBox3.Text = v[2].ToString();
```

If you want to use the cell value in a textbox, for example.

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to your answer